# Reading "pure" bytes in C

Tags: c, binary, byte

I was wondering.. how do you read bytes one at a time from a binary file? As an example, I'd like to read bytes one at a time from some binary file and then write those exact bytes to some output file (basically a very basic implementation of the `cp` command). My current C code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <output file>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *outfile;
    outfile = fopen(argv[1], "w");

    unsigned char c;
    char temp;
    int tracker = 0;
    // Use temp because unsigned char will never be EOF
    while ((temp = getchar()) != EOF) {
        c = (unsigned char) temp;
        fprintf(outfile, "%c", c);
    }
fclose(outfile);
return 0;
}
```

I run the program like this: `./main output.au < sample.au` (.au is an audio file)

However, all I get in the `output.au` file is a bunch of "^@" repeated over and over. I can play the `sample.au` audio file fine, but not the `output.au`. I've also (somewhat pointlessly) done a `diff` on the two files, and as expected they come out differently.

Help?
Thanks!
-kstruct

*UPDATE*
Thanks for the reply everyone.. my code now looks like:

```
outfile = fopen(argv[1], "wb");

int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    fprintf(outfile, "%c", c);
}
```

Comment: Normally you would read/write blocks of `pure` bytes in C as opposed to the single byte approach.

Comment: @kstruct Your updated code works for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`getchar()` returns an `int`.
You assign that `int` to a variable of type `char` thereby losing information. **Don't do that.**

Declare `temp` as int, and go get rid of the cast.

Comment: I see, makes sense I agree with everything. However I still seem to be having the problem.. my updated code is up above.. help? Thanks!

Comment: Ah ah! You're redirecting input from a file to `stdin`. `stdin` is a text-mode stream and not really suitable for what you're doing. Anyway ... do you have "^@"'s in the input file?

Comment: Nope, the input file is a bunch of jumbled garbage-looking things.. hm `stdin` seems to work when I do a straight off `getchar()` followed by the `fprintf`, but seems to stop working when I store the `c` into an `unsigned int[]` and then write the array at some other time... thoughts?

Comment: There should be no difference between text-mode and binary-mode streams in Linux (which you're apparently using). As for change in behaviour when you pass the data through an `unsigned int[]` I have no idea ... **how does it "stop working"?**

Answer (score 2):

There are several things that need to get fixed:
1) Reopen STDIN as binary. `freopen(NULL, "rb", stdin);`
2) Open the outfile as: fopen(argv[1], "wb");
3) temp needs to be of type *int*.

Comment: According to [the C99 Standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#7.19.5.4) "It is implementation-defined which changes of mode are permitted (if any), and under what circumstances."

Comment: Given his condition of not requiring, that, he's on UNIX.

Answer (score 0):

make the following corrections:

```
- outfile = fopen(argv[1], "w");
+ outfile = fopen(argv[1], "wb");


- c = (unsigned char) temp;
+ c = (unsigned char) (char) temp;
```

Comment: `c` is already a `char`, the new cast is useless.  As pmg says above, `c` should be an `int`, but I see no need to cast through `char` even in that case.

Comment: It isn't a char after he fixes the other one. I've gotten burned a few times when narrowing and changing signed-ness on the same cast.

Comment: `getchar` returns, if not `EOF`, an `unsigned char` cast to an `int`.  The reverse ought to work.

Comment: Good point. If temp can never be negative, only one cast is required.